# how to use netlify form in nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, forms, email, next.js, netlify

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A3vV.png)

When I hit the submit button, it doesn't redirect me to the /success page
and it does not send the message to my netlify panel as it should happen

I was already guided by the documentation but it has not worked for me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong if someone was already able to make this work thanks

Comment: Hi @Hennrrycin123, To provide you with a more helpful answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide additional details about your specific issue or question. It would be great if you could include some code snippets or examples to illustrate the problem you're facing.